# corrupt usb flash drive, complains about /dev/sdc, but there is nothing there where do I find it?

Tags: usb, mount, fat32

How can I reset this drive?, there is no /dev/sdc*. ubuntu-disks does not list it. It was fat32 formatted on win7:

```
Nov  8 17:42:13 mortenb upowerd[1783]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-3
Nov  8 17:42:13 mortenb upowerd[1783]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.0
Nov  8 17:42:14 mortenb kernel: [  214.646341] scsi 12:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Ultra Fit        1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Nov  8 17:42:14 mortenb kernel: [  214.646700] sd 12:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Nov  8 17:42:14 mortenb kernel: [  214.646951] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] 30375936 512-byte logical blocks: (15.6 GB/14.5 GiB)
Nov  8 17:42:14 mortenb kernel: [  214.648143] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
Nov  8 17:42:14 mortenb kernel: [  214.648146] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
Nov  8 17:42:14 mortenb kernel: [  214.649142] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Nov  8 17:42:14 mortenb kernel: [  214.681452]  sdc: sdc1
Nov  8 17:42:14 mortenb kernel: [  214.684138] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
Nov  8 17:42:14 mortenb kernel: [  214.852335] FAT-fs (sdc1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
Nov  8 17:42:14 mortenb systemd[1]: Created slice system-clean\x2dmount\x2dpoint.slice.
Nov  8 17:42:14 mortenb systemd[1]: Started Clean the /media/mortenb/PS4 mount point.
Nov  8 17:42:14 mortenb udisksd[1029]: Mounted /dev/sdc1 at /media/mortenb/pen1 on behalf of uid 1000
Nov  8 17:42:46 mortenb kernel: [  246.852074] usb 2-3: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Nov  8 17:42:51 mortenb kernel: [  252.068380] usb 2-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
```

Comment: It's a Sandisk 16G flash drive.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, usually I have opposite situation, USB that is unusable on Windows and nothing helps.

In such situations it's easiest and most user friendly to us Gparted:
https://gparted.org/

It had been standard tool in Ubuntu and other Linux distros for years (should I say decades?), has GUI, is relatively user friendly, and most of all - extremely powerful.

Since you solved your issue all I can give you is this recommendation.

If you have empty USB play with it for 5 minutes, you should be good!

Comment: Thanks for mentioning gparted. I'll definetely try it out

Comment: I'm sure you'll find it great :)

Answer (score 0):

I borrowed a win10 laptop, entered disk management and re-partitioned it as a primary ntfs drive, then I was able to mount it. Turned out the partition header was corrupt.

But I only have ubuntu 16.04/18.04 and would very much learn how to do this in ubuntu with lsusb/fdisk/fsck.fat etc.